# Pick subtitle file from storage and load in ExoPlayer

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an app that plays videos using ExoPlayer but I wanted to add an option to pick and load any subtitle file into the player.

This is my code for subtitle:

```
    public void setSubSelectedSubtitle(MediaSource mediaSource, String subtitle, Context context) {
        MergingMediaSource mergedSource;
        if (subtitle != null) {
            Uri subtitleUri = Uri.parse(subtitle);

            Format subtitleFormat = Format.createTextSampleFormat(
                    null, // An identifier for the track. May be null.
                    MimeTypes.TEXT_VTT, // The mime type. Must be set correctly.
                    Format.NO_VALUE, // Selection flags for the track.
                    "en"); // The subtitle language. May be null.

            DefaultDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(context,
                    Util.getUserAgent(context, getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)), new DefaultBandwidthMeter());


            MediaSource subtitleSource = new SingleSampleMediaSource
                    .Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                    .createMediaSource(subtitleUri, subtitleFormat, C.TIME_UNSET);


            mergedSource = new MergingMediaSource(mediaSource, subtitleSource);
            player.prepare(mergedSource, false, false);
            //resumePlayer();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "there is no subtitle", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

What I'm trying is, when the user clicks on subtitle button, it should open their storage from which they could choose the file which should get loaded and play in ExoPlayer.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: you want to pick and pass the subtitle file URL to 'String subtitle' ?

Comment: Not URL, but the file itself (.srt) @Jacks

Comment: You can use intent to open explorer and get the URI for the file - pass it to the SRT loading method.

Comment: Could you tell me how to do it via code? @Jacks Sorry if I'm asking you for too much!

Comment: added as answer below -  step by step.